# change value of a key of an array within an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array within an array like:

```
$some_large_array = array(
    'person' => array('name' => 'stefanie', 'hobby' => 'rock climbing',),
    'dog' => array('name' => 'orbit', 'hobby' => 'chewing curtains'));
```

How can I change the value of of 'hobby' of 'dog' and return it as 'napping'?

Comment: $some_large_array['dog']['hobby'] = 'chewing curtains an peeing'; access keys

Comment: aahhh I seee! that makes total sense! thank you!

Comment: does this work with booleans as well, like can I set things to true or false?

Comment: Why ask, when you can just try it out?

Comment: @Rizier123 you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access array keys like this, in your example:

```
$some_large_array['dog']['hobby'] = 'napping';
```

(answering to remove from "unanswered" queue)